What is the first integral of a Lagrangian system?
A question from Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics, Arnold, P90:

Extend Noether's theorem to non-autonomous Lagrangian systems.

There is a hint :

Let $M_1=M\times\mathbb{R}$ be the extended configuration space (the direct product of the configuration manifold $M$ with the time axis $\mathbb{R}$).
Define a function $L_1:TM\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
$$
  L\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}\tau}
  $$
i.e., in local coordinates $\textbf{q}, t$ on $M_1$ we define it by the formula
$$
  L_1\left( \textbf{q},t,\frac{\mathrm{d}\textbf{q}}{\mathrm{d}\tau},\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\right)=L\left(\textbf{q},\frac{\mathrm{d}\textbf{q}/\mathrm{d}\tau}{\mathrm{d}t/\mathrm{d}\tau},t\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}\tau}
  $$
We apply Noether's theorem to the Lagrangian system $\left( M_1, L_1 \right)$.

ps: An autonomous version of Noether's theorem has been demonstrated before, and here is the statement:

If the system $\left(M,L\right)$ admits the one-parameter group of diffeomorphisms $h^s: M \rightarrow M, s\in\mathbb{R}$, then the Lagrangian system of equations corresponding to $L$ has a first integral $I: TM \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
In local coordinates q on M the integral I is written in the form
$$
  I\left(\textbf{q},\mathbf{\dot q}\right)=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{\dot q}}\frac{\mathrm{d}h^s\left(\mathbf{q}\right)}{\mathrm{d}s}\bigg|_{s=0}
  $$

I do the calculation as below, hope I do it right:
If $L_1$ admits $h^s:M_1 \rightarrow M_1$, then
$$
I_1=\left(\frac{\partial L_1}{\partial \mathrm{d}\mathbf{q}/\mathrm{d}\tau},\frac{\partial L_1}{\partial \mathrm{d}t/\mathrm{d}\tau}\right)\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}h^s}{\mathrm{d}s}\bigg|_{s=0}
$$
$$
\because \frac{\partial L_1}{\partial \mathrm{d}\mathbf{q}/\mathrm{d}\tau}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathrm{d}\mathbf{q}/\mathrm{d}\tau}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}\tau}+\frac{\partial \mathrm{d}t/\mathrm{d}\tau}{\partial \mathrm{d}\mathbf{q}/\mathrm{d}\tau}\cdot L= \frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{\dot q}},  \frac{\partial L_1}{\partial \mathrm{d}t/\mathrm{d}\tau}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathrm{d}t/\mathrm{d}\tau}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}\tau}+\frac{\partial \mathrm{d}t/\mathrm{d}\tau}{\partial \mathrm{d}t/\mathrm{d}\tau}\cdot L= L-\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{\dot q}}\mathbf{\dot q}
$$
$$
\therefore I_1=\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{\dot q}}, L-\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{\dot q}}\mathbf{\dot q}\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}h^s}{\mathrm{d}s}\bigg|_{s=0}
$$
This is a nice result because the left in the bracket is cyclic integral and the right one is energy integral. However, this demonstration needs to permit $I_1=I$, but I can't figure out why. Obviously this is due to the construction of $L_1$, but I don't know why $L_1$ makes sense. There is an explanation in the book:

Since $\int L \mathrm{d}t=\int L_1 \mathrm{d}\tau$, this reduces to a first integral $I: TM\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of the original system.

I can't fully understand this statement, as well as the concept of first integral of a Lagrangian system. Can anyone tell me why $\int L \mathrm{d}t$ makes sense and what on earth is a first integral? Thanks!

The first page here should answer your question on what a first integral is.

@MatthewCassell Thanks for your comment and I think I've got an answer. I'll update it later.
